# Deny app access to audio input device settings

Tags: windows-10, audio

I am having an issue with CS:GO changing a certain input device to 100% every time the game is started.
I have tried setting other devices as the default device.
I have tried denying CS:GO and Steam access to microphone.

I attempted to use VB-CABLE, but the thing is the volume of the actual device is still changed to 100%.

I can't find an option in the game settings. Can't find a command in the config.
I have searched the web for a solution for days now and am growing quite tired of changing the settings every single time I launch CS:GO.

Is there some way I can require admin access to adjust the sound settings?
Or can I somehow change a key reg to disallow an app access?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.  Audio settings, such as volume, are always *user* changeable.  Therefore, CS:GO, or any program launched by a *user*, has access to change the audio settings.

However, you could write a script or program to automatically set the audio settings back to their desired settings.  I would do some Googling, there may very well be people who have the same or similar issue as you, and have already created a solution.